# PostgresXL pgxc_ctl connection refused when adding coordinator

Tags: postgres-xl

Following tutorial on https://github.com/bitnine-oss/postgres-xl-ha/blob/master/README.md, I get the following error when trying to add coordinator (using pgxc_ctl):

Actual Command:

```
PGXC add coordinator master coord komp2 30001 30011 none none none
```

Bring remote stdout:

```
ssh aaron@komp2 "( PGXC_CTL_SILENT=1 initdb -D $dataDirRoot/coord --nodename coord ) > /tmp/skripsi_STDOUT_17620_12 2>&1" < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1
scp aaron@komp2:/tmp/skripsi_STDOUT_17620_12 /tmp/STDOUT_17620_13 > /dev/null 2>&1
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "aaron".
This user must also own the server process.
initdb: invalid locale settings; check LANG and LC_* environment variables
bash: /home/aaron/DATA/pgxl/nodes/coord/postgresql.conf: No such file or directory
bash: /home/aaron/DATA/pgxl/nodes/coord/pg_hba.conf: No such file or directory
ERROR: failed to find any running coordinatorStarting coordinator master coord
pg_ctl: directory "/home/aaron/DATA/pgxl/nodes/coord" does not exist
Done.
```

> ```
> psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
> Is the server running on host "komp2" (192.168.38.21) and accepting
> TCP/IP connections on port 30001?
> ```

What probably cause it? Thanks in advance

Comment: `initdb` failed ("*initdb: invalid locale settings....*") and thus the node wasn't created to begin with. And if it's not created you can't connect

Comment: then what can I do about this? should I install a postgres on "komp2" manually, and then adding postgresql.conf & pg_hba.conf?